# imprimir uma variavel int em C

Tags: c

estou precisando de uma ajuda.

quero imprimir o valor de uma variável int decidida pelo scanf, mas quando compilo e rodo o programa ele me retorna o seguinte valor:

"digite o valor de A --->11

o valor digitado foi: 6422300"

meu código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("digite o valor de A --->");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\n o valor digitado foi: %d", &a);



    return 0;
}
```

desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você está tentando imprimir `&a`, que é o endereço de memória da variável `a`. Para imprimir o que você deseja, como no exemplo a seguir, retire o `&`:

```
printf("Variável: %d", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa tirar o sinal **&** (ampersand) do segundo `printf` do seu código.

O correto seria `printf("\n o valor digitado foi: %d", a);`

Answer (score 1):

Na hora de printar a variável não se usa o `&`, somente a variável que deseja imprimir;
o correto seria: `printf("o valor digitado foi:%d",a);`